# How to find most popular genre of music?

Tags: mysql, database

So I have two tables, table 1:Music Styles being with fields with StyleID and StyleName, with StyleName being a genre and table 2:entertainers with fields SyleID and EntertainerID.

I need help finding is:

1)  What’s the most popular genre of music style in the database of entertainers?

This is what i have so far:

```
 SELECT StyleID, StyleName 
   from EA_Music_Styles
  WHERE StyleID = (SELECT StyleID 
                     from EA_Entertainer_Styles 
                    WHERE StyleID = (SELECT MAX(StyleID) 
                                       FROM EA_Entertainer_Styles));
```

But i got an error code of "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

I need help, don't know exactly what to do? First time beginner.

Here are the tables:
Table 1:
StyleID    StyleN
1         40's Ballroom Music
2         50's Music
3         60's Music
4         70's Music
5         80's Music
6         Country
7         Classical
8         Classic Rock & Roll
9         Rap
10        Contemporary
11        Country Rock
12        Elvis
13        Folk
14        Chamber Music
15        Jazz
16        Karaoke
17        Motown
18        Modern Rock
19        Rhythm and Blues
20        Show Tunes
21        Standards
22        Top 40 Hits
23        Variety
24        Salsa
25        90's Music

Table 2:

StyleID  EntertainerID
3        1003
3        1008
4        1010
6        1007
6        1008
7        1009
7        1011
7        1012
8        1003
10       1001
10       1013
11       1007
13       1004
13       1012
14       1009
14       1011
15       1005
15       1013
17       1002
19       1002
19       1005
20       1001
20       1011
21       1001
21       1009
21       1010
22       1006
22       1010
23       1002
23       1006
24       1005
24       1006

SO the result would output the two StyleID's, 7 & 21 and StyleName which would be Classical & Standards

Comment: also do remember that the MAX gives the maximum value not the most occurring value. To get the most used value you have to group by and count.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join your two tables and get the max count for entertainers

```
 SELECT ms.StyleName, count(*) most_popular
   from EA_Music_Styles ms
         INNER JOIN A_Entertainer_Styles es
         ON ms.StyleID = es.StyleID
  group by ms.StyleName
  order by 2 desc
  limit 1
```

This will give you the most popular (I take that it is the one that has more rows) StyleName. I count the ocurrences of StyleName and order it desc getting only the first result of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve the problem.

1. In your entertainers table user group by StyleID while also selecting the count. This will give you the styleID count which you can sort by descending and limit 1 to find to most popular one

   ```
   select StyleID, count(StyleID) c from EA_Entertainer_Styles
   group by StyleID
   order by c desc
   limit 1;
   ```
2. Now use the styleID form the first step to get the StyleName from your table Music.

   ```
   select StyleName from EA_Music_Styles
   where StyleID = id_from_step1
   ```

You can use this two in a single query by joining them as in the answer shown by [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383534/1935941)

Answer (score 0):

Max gives you the highest number in the database, not the most used. You should use count for that.

Next example should give correct result.

```
select StyleName from EA_Music_Styles
where StyleID = (
     select StyleID
     from EA_Entertainer_Styles
     group by StyleID
     order by count(StyleID) desc
     limit 1)
```

Comment: But this only shows 1 StyleName, there should be 2, if i change the limit it shows an error

Comment: you can't change the limit since you use "StyleID = (select...".
To keep this, you can only have one result in the second select statement.

To get all values that might be equal. You should fist get the most used StyleID's and then their names, one minute please

Comment: select StyleName from EA_Music_Styles
where StyleID in (
select b.StyleID
from EA_Entertainer_Styles b
group by b.StyleID
having count(b.StyleID) =(select count(a.StyleID) 
                        from EA_Entertainer_Styles a
                        group by a.StyleID
                        order by a.StyleID
                        limit 1)
)